# iOS: NetInfo.isConnected returns always false

Tags: ios, xcode, reactjs, react-native

`netInfo` React Native always returns `false` in ios simulator

```
NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
    if (isConnected == true) {
        this.setState({isOnline: true})
        this.checkForToken()
    }
    else {
        this.setState({isOnline: false})
        this.checkTokenOffline()
    }
});

NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then().done(() => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener('connectionChange', (isConnected) => this.dispatchConnected());
})
```

Comment: did you test on real device ?. pls also add RN version.

Comment: It still not working. Check this [issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8615) . my project use `NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener` instead

Comment: its working properly in real devices

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a [known bug](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/8615) where it always gives false. You'll need to attach a listener and use that instead.

```
yourFunction = () => {
    NetInfo.isConnected.fetch().then(isConnected => {
        //Always false, so ignore/do nothing here
    });
    NetInfo.isConnected.addEventListener(
        'connectionChange',
        this.handleFirstConnectivityChange
    );
}

handleFirstConnectivityChange = (isConnected) => {
    if (isConnected == true) {
        this.setState({isOnline: true})
        this.checkForToken()
    }
    else {
        this.setState({isOnline: false})
        this.checkTokenOffline()
    }
}
```